# How do I change the plot area of a chart in excel?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have created a new chart in my excel workbook and am trying to re dimension the plot area but my code does not seem to be working. Any help?

```
        GlobVars.Wksht = GlobVars.Wkbk.Sheets(1) 'sets current working sheet as first sheet in wkbook
    GlobVars.xlCharts = GlobVars.Wksht.ChartObjects
    GlobVars.myChart = GlobVars.xlCharts.Add(30, 30, 800, 400) 'changes the starting location and height and width
    GlobVars.chartPage = GlobVars.myChart.Chart

    GlobVars.chartPage = GlobVars.myChart.Chart
    GlobVars.chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatter 'changes chart type
    GlobVars.chartPage.PlotArea.Width = 600
    GlobVars.chartPage.PlotArea.Height = 300
```

The last two lines are the lines I am trying to work with. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run that?  Do you get an error?

Comment: did u set `AutoLayout` and `uniformaxis` to `false` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I did not have my chart plot area set to my actual chart object so I was getting a null value error exception.

Here's my code bit I have:

```
Dim chartPage As Excel.Chart
        Dim xlCharts As Excel.ChartObjects
        Dim myChart As Excel.ChartObject
        Dim chartRange As Excel.Range

        GlobVars.Wksht = GlobVars.Wkbk.Sheets(1) 'sets current active sheet
        GlobVars.Wksht.Activate()
        xlCharts = GlobVars.Wksht.ChartObjects
        myChart = xlCharts.Add(30, 30, 800, 600) 'changes chart height, width, and starting corner
        chartPage = myChart.Chart 'assign "chartPage" to myChart (this was my error before)
        chartPage.PlotArea.Width = 500
        chartPage.PlotArea.Height = 600
        chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatter 'changes chart type
```

Answer (score 0):

How about finding the last used row, and last used column, using this concept?

```
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Also, loop through objects to find a chart and assign a name to said chart.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
    cht.Activate

    'Do something with the chart...

  Next cht
Next sht
```

You will almost certainly want to make changes to the chart object after it is identified and selected.  You can look for sample code online, or simply record a Macro and click through the steps to need to perform.  Update the generic 'chart1', 'chart2', 'chart3', etc, with the name you derived in the example above.  Mix the recorded Macro code with the code I posted here, and you are in business.